# Creating a "Numbers Grid" with for() *logic thing*

Tags: php

i have a litte bit a special questions. I want to create a dynamic 3 column table. I played a litte bit with the for element, because later i want to get data from a mysql.

So far i wrote this code to test the logic(It doesn't matter the layout at this point):

```
$count = $_GET['zahl'];
$c1 = $count / 3;
$c2 = ceil($c1);

for($i=0; $i < $c2; $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";
}
echo "<hr>";
for($i=$c2; $i <($c2 * 2); $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";}

echo "<hr>";
for($i=($c2 * 2); $i <$count; $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";}
```

How it works:
Put 3, 6, 9 ... it works great. Equal columns.
Put for example 8  in it, it works great too. It makes 3 in the first, 3 in the second, 2 in the last. 
Put for example 7 in it it doesn't work. It makes 3,3,1 instead of 3,2,2.

how should i change the code so far that numbers like 7, 10, 13 and so on are working?

EDIT: The goal is to get something like 3,2,2 oder 4,3,3 and so on.

Comment: You did not give a definition of "works" or what you consider "correct". Currently the code "works as implemented": it always fills a row before starting to insert into a fresh one. So the question is less how to implement your goal, but more: what _is_ your goal? Why `3,2,2` in your example? Why do you consider that "correct" whilst "`3,3,1` is considered "wrong"?

Comment: I'm Sorry, I would like to have a 3,2,2 thing because it fits nicer in the layout :)

Comment: Can you please clear more.How you want for 10 13 16?

Comment: I'm sorry for my expression in english. For 10 = 4,3,3 ; 13 = 5, 4, 4 ; 16 = 6, 5,5 the second and the third should be even.

Comment: note that you're not generating columns in this code, you're just generating three lines of text without any markup other than "break the line here", which is a very different thing. It would be far wiser to generate marked up values, and then styling them appropriated with CSS. (e.g. generate `<div><span>v1</span><span>...</div><div><span>v4...</div><div>...</div>`)

Comment: Yes of curse these are not columns, just wanted to makes the logic work first and did't wanted to spam you with the markups &#128540;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
$count = $_GET['zahl'];
$c1 = ceil($count / 3);
$rem = $count - $c1;
$c2 = ceil($rem / 2);     
$c3 = floor($rem / 2);

for($i=0; $i < $c1; $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";
}
echo "<hr>";

for($i=$c1; $i < ($c1 + $c2); $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";}

echo "<hr>";
for($i=($c1 + $c2); $i <$count; $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";
}
```

Divide count by 3, store in c1. Calculate remaining fields, store in rem. Divide remainder by 2, store the ceil of that number in c2, and the floor in c3.

Btw. I am not familiar with this syntax so this may not work as-is.

Comment: I added two missing ; and not it works. Great idear, thank you very much. I found another solution now. Will post it if someone else is looking for one.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
    $count = $_GET['zahl'];
$c1 = $count / 3;
$c2 = ceil($c1);
$rest = $count - $c2 ;

for($i=0; $i < $c2; $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";
}
echo "<hr>";
for($i=$c2; $i <$c2 + ceil($rest/2); $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";}

echo "<hr>";
for($i=($c2 + ceil($rest/2)); $i <$count; $i++){
    echo "".$i."<br>";}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$count = $_GET['zahl'];

    $c1=$c2=$c3=floor($count / 3);
    $reminder=($count%3);
    if($reminder==1)
    {
        $c1++;
    }
    elseif($reminder==2)
    {
        $c1++;
        $c2++;
    }

    for($i=0;$i<$c1;$i++)
    {
        echo "".$i."<br>";
    }
    echo "<hr>";
    for($i=$c1;$i<($c1+$c2);$i++)
    {
        echo "".$i."<br>";
    }
    echo "<hr>";
    for($i=($c1+$c2);$i<($c1+$c2+$c3);$i++)
    {
        echo "".$i."<br>";
    }
```

Even you can make these 3 loops using one loop.Like this

```
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        if(($i==$c1)||($i==($c1+$c2)))
        {
            echo "<hr>";
        }
        echo "".$i."<br>";
    }
```

**NOTE**
 You can do `echo $i."<br>";` instead of `echo "".$i."<br>";`